# Javascript copy div text and split into an input

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone been trying to copy text from a div to an input on a button click
i got it to where it copy the text but i don't want to copy the full line
so i was wondering is there away i could copy each name separate to the input??

```js
var namesButton = document.getElementById("names");
namesButton.addEventListener("click", names);

var counter = 0;

function names() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("hud-leaderboard-party");
  var lastElem = elems[counter];
  document.getElementsByClassName("hud-intro-name")[0].value = lastElem.innerText;
  counter += 1;
  if (counter >= elems.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hud-intro-leaderboard-parties">
  <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">name one, name two, — <strong>1000</strong></div>
  <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">name three, name four, — <strong>1000</strong></div>
  <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">name five, — <strong>1000</strong></div>
</div>

<input type="text" class="hud-intro-name" style="width: 50%;"> &nbsp;
<button id="names" style="width: 40%;">copy name to input</button>
```

Comment: What's the pattern you want to create?

Comment: You can wrap text in tag(for example span) and select  text from this tag

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming "get the names separated?" in your question means getting only the text content of  tag without the inner  tag content.

One simple way is to wrap text content in a tag as suggested by @Сергей Петрашко in comment.

If the HTML cannot be modified then you can use childNodes textContent property instead of lastElem.innerText;

So in your function,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hud-intro-name")[0].value = lastElem.innerText;
```

above line can be modified as

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hud-intro-name")[0].value=lastElem.childNodes[0].textContent;
```

But still " — " would be there with the names as its part of the  tags text content, which you should be able to remove by splitting the string or something like that.

Comment: sorry for late reply i had really bad chest pain a had to get offline. when i say get the names separated i mean get each name "name one" than "name two" and so on.

Comment: That you should be able to do with simple split function right? Like
`lastElem.childNodes[0].textContent.split(",")`
This would give an array which you can loop and extract the names required.